# How to take a screenshot using a Lumia 800?

Tags: nokia-lumia-800, screenshot

Is there an application like [Screen Capturer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1316199) for Nokia Lumia 800? I can't find any in the Marketplace.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Phone 7.x doesn't have inbuilt support for screen capture. However if you have a phone that is (a) developer unlocked and (b) interop-unlocked there’s an app you can use for taking screen shots on your device. The app is called [Screen Capturer](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_take_screenshot_on_Windows_Phone)